# Number of Apache HTTP Processes on Windows

Tags: apache-2.2

I use Apache on Windows.  I always see at least 2 **http.exe** entries in process list on Windows Task Manager.  Most of the time it is in the range of 3 -5.

What is the number of http.exe instances correlated to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Apache uses the [mpm_winnt](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_winnt.html) multiprocess module (MPM) to manage processes.  You'll notice in the documentation that it will launch a "single control process which launches a single child process which in turn creates threads to handle requests."  The additional processes you're seeing are most likely the additional threads that are being created.